# How to use the OpenID Connect WebFinger Endpoint?

Tags: http, security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

Reading the [description here](https://connect2id.com/learn/openid-connect#optional-endpoints) it says:

> WebFinger — Enables dynamic discovery of the OpenID Connect provider for a given user, based on their email address or some other information.

Can someone give an example of how this works (Description is somewhat abstract)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebFinger is a protocol defined in [RFC7033](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7033). There is a complete example in [section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7033#section-3.1):

> **3.1.   Identity Provider Discovery for OpenID Connect**
>
> Suppose Carol wishes to authenticate with a web site she visits using
> OpenID Connect.  She would provide the web site with her OpenID
> Connect identifier, say carol@example.com.  The visited web site
> would perform a WebFinger query looking for the OpenID Connect
> provider.  Since the site is interested in only one particular link
> relation, the WebFinger resource might utilize the "rel" parameter as
> described in Section 4.3:

> ```
> GET /.well-known/webfinger?
> ```

```
        resource=acct%3Acarol%40example.com&
        rel=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fspecs%2Fconnect%2F1.0%2Fissuer
        HTTP/1.1
 Host: example.com
```

> The server might respond like this:

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> ```

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
 Content-Type: application/jrd+json
```

> ```
> {
> ```

```
   "subject" : "acct:carol@example.com",
   "links" :
   [
     {
       "rel" : "http://openid.net/specs/connect/1.0/issuer",
       "href" : "https://openid.example.com"
     }
   ]
 }
```

> Since the "rel" parameter only serves to filter the link relations
> returned by the resource, other name/value pairs in the response,
> including any aliases or properties, would be returned.  Also, since
> support for the "rel" parameter is not guaranteed, the client must
> not assume the "links" array will contain only the requested link
> relation.

Comment: Is this only an illustration or a real specification?